# Build images using Qemu for ARM/x86 on x86

Tags: docker, x86, arm, qemu

I'm trying to understand how to build arm images on x86 [here](https://blog.hypriot.com/post/setup-simple-ci-pipeline-for-arm-images/), but i'm having hard time.

What I would like to achieve is the following:

- Have a single dockerfile to build both ARM/x86 images.
- Have a command to execute on the CI agent that explicitly define the architecture for which I want to build my image.

The steps seems to be the following:

1. Add binary of QEMU for ARM in the base image. Everybody suggests to use prebuilt images with the binary in it (like `resin/rpi-raspbian`)
2. Register the QEMU binary in the CI build agent by running the following command: `docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static:register -- reset`

Beside the fact that I don't understand all the magic underneath these 2 steps, I kind of understand step 2 after trying it on my laptop: 
It generates a bunch of binaries which need to be used to simulate the desired architecture.

- If I'm generating binaries using command in step 2, why would I need an image with binary of QEMU for ARM in it?
- My current base image is a `debian:strech` and I can generate an ARM image successfully on an ARM device, why would I need to use an ARM specific image? Can't I achieve what I need keeping the `debian:strech`? I'm asking this, because I would like to have a single docker file to build images for both x86 and ARM.

If someone could bring some light on this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I wanted to leave this blog post for reference:

How to Build and Run ARM Docker Images on x86

https://matchboxdorry.gitbooks.io/matchboxblog/content/blogs/build_and_run_arm_images.html

And you can also check how to add multiplatform builds in GH actions:

https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/multi-platform/